# hibernate4-maven-plugin not finding annotated classes

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, maven

I have the hibernate4-maven-plugin running but it isn't finding my annotated class and therfore generating an empty output file.

If I run the goal it tells me it is scanning the correct folder but it only finds two classes from a dependecy, not my annotated class.

```
[DEBUG] Detected classes with mapping-annotations:
[DEBUG]   org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.AbstractAuditable
[DEBUG]   org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.AbstractPersistable
```

My class:

```
package ch.tbz.schooltool.schooltoolbackend;

import ch.tbz.schooltool.schooltoolbackend.person.Gender;
import ch.tbz.schooltool.schooltoolbackend.person.Role;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDate;

@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id")
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "person_id_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "person_id_seq", sequenceName = "person_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    Integer id;

    String firstName;

    String lastName;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    Gender gender;

    LocalDate dateOfBirth;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    Role role;
}
```

My POM plugin:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>de.juplo</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate4-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>export</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <hibernateProperties>${project.basedir}/schooltool-db/hibernate.hbm2ddl.properties
                    </hibernateProperties>
                    <outputFile>${project.basedir}/schooltool-db/create_ddl_generated.sql</outputFile>
                    <target>SCRIPT</target>
                    <type>CREATE</type>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

My config:

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL81Dialect
hibernate.connection.charSet=UTF-8
hibernate.export.schema.delimiter=;
hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=true
hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
```

Comment: Are you aware of that there is [a newer version of de.juplo:hibernate4-maven-plugin](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:de.juplo%20AND%20a:hibernate4-maven-plugin&core=gav)?

Comment: Thank you very much, upgrading to 1.1.1 solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Gerold Broser mentioned there are newer versions available. Using version 1.1.1 solved my problem.